# Customize ListItem contains colorful label, colorful label background not show?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, qlistwidget

I customize `QListView` and `ListItem`, the `ListItem` contain colorful label,but the colorful label not working?I can't find why the `QLabel` not show it's color.

**Demo code**

```py
from qtpy.QtWidgets import *
from qtpy.QtCore import *
from qtpy.QtGui import *

class ListItem(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, color, info):
        super().__init__()
        lay = QHBoxLayout()
        self._colorLabel = QLabel()
        self._info = QLabel(info)

        lay.addWidget(self._colorLabel)
        lay.addWidget(self._info)
        self.setLayout(lay)

        self._colorLabel.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.setLabelColor(color)

    def setLabelColor(self, color):
        pal = self._colorLabel.palette()
        pal.setColor(QPalette.Window, color)
        self._colorLabel.setPalette(pal)

class ListWiget(QListWidget):
    def _addItem(self, item):
        tmpItem = QListWidgetItem()
        tmpItem.setSizeHint(item.sizeHint())
        self.addItem(tmpItem)
        self.setItemWidget(tmpItem, item)


app = QApplication([])

listW = ListWiget()
item = ListItem(Qt.red, "red")
item2 = ListItem(Qt.blue, "blue")
listW._addItem((item2))
listW._addItem(item)
listW.show()

app.exec()
```

**The Picture**
It always show white background?
[image]

Comment: If add stylesheet `self._colorLabel.setStyleSheet("QLabel {background:yellow;}")`  will work,I also want the post method can work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `Base` instead of `Window`:

```py
def setLabelColor(self, color):
    pal = self._colorLabel.palette()
    pal.setColor(QPalette.Base, color)
    self._colorLabel.setPalette(pal)
```

Comment: Or, alternatively, explicitly set the background role to avoid that it uses the parent override from the view: `self._colorLabel.setBackgroundRole(QPalette.Window)`

Comment: Now solve this problem have 3 methods.Thanks YOU Very Much.